# libkrb5-dev install on databricks sometimes works, other times not

Tags: 20.04, package-management, updates, kerberos

I’m facing issues when I try to install `libkrb5-dev` on databricks. Sometimes I can do the installation other times I get 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80] error.

`apt-get update`, `clean` etc. won’t help.
For me it looks like the error occurs randomly so I believe the problem is either connected to networking or to the ubuntu repository. ([link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/) to the focal-updates that are connected to the problem.)

The `libkrb5-dev` package needs to be installed every time when the databricks cluster is started.
The only way I found to ‘solve’ the problem is not letting terminate the cluster once the installation was successful. (It is an expensive work around and I don’t like it.)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the apt lists before updating and installing the package.

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libkrb5-dev
```